# handle multiple pandas merge with nulls

Tags: python, pandas

I have three data frames:

Frame1:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'instrument': ['a','b','c'], 'CUSIP': ['US1',np.NaN,'US2'],'ISIN':[np.NaN,"EU1",np.NaN]}
ip = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
ip
```

Frame2:

```
cusipid={'CUSIP':['a','c'],'ID':["a1","c1"]}
cusipmap=pd.DataFrame(data=cusipid)
cusipmap
```

Frame3:

```
isinid={'ISIN':['b','c'],'ID':["b1","c2"]}
isinmap=pd.DataFrame(data=isinid)
isinmap
```

I want to add a column to frame 1 , keeping the number of rows in Frame 1 constant ( left join) by first joining on CUSIP on Frame 2 and Then with ISIN on Frame 3. HOWEVER, I want to do the ISIN join on frame 3 only if there is a NaN produced as part of the Frame 2 join. SO, the output that I am looking for is something like:

```
op= {'instrument': ['a','b','c'], 'CUSIP': ['US1',np.NaN,'US2'],'ISIN':[np.NaN,"EU1",np.NaN],'ID':['a1','b1','c1']}
op = pd.DataFrame(data=op)
op
```

Does the pd.merge have any functionality to perform the operations above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new `Series` with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and then replace missing values by another Series with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
s1 = ip['instrument'].map(cusipmap.set_index('CUSIP')['ID'])
s2 = ip['instrument'].map(isinmap.set_index('ISIN')['ID'])
ip['Id'] = s1.fillna(s2)
print (ip)
  instrument CUSIP ISIN  Id
0          a   US1  NaN  a1
1          b   NaN  EU1  b1
2          c   US2  NaN  c1
```

Solution with `merge`:

```
s1 = ip.merge(cusipmap.rename(columns={'CUSIP':'instrument'}),on='instrument',how='left')['ID']
s2 = ip.merge(isinmap.rename(columns={'ISIN':'instrument'}),on='instrument',how='left')['ID']

ip['Id'] = s1.combine_first(s2)
print (ip)
  instrument CUSIP ISIN  Id
0          a   US1  NaN  a1
1          b   NaN  EU1  b1
2          c   US2  NaN  c1
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! what about if I had to do more than two joins ?

Comment: @NumberLogic - Then use `ip['Id'] = s1.fillna(s2).fillna(s3)` - `s3` is coun similar like `s1, s2`

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it would be to merge both dataframes and then build the desired column using `.loc`. Example below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'instrument': ['a','b','c'], 'CUSIP': ['US1',np.NaN,'US2'],'ISIN':[np.NaN,"EU1",np.NaN]}
ip = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

cusipid={'CUSIP':['a','c'],'ID':["a1","c1"]}
cusipmap=pd.DataFrame(data=cusipid)

isinid={'ISIN':['b','c'],'ID':["b1","c2"]}
isinmap=pd.DataFrame(data=isinid)


df = (ip
      .merge(cusipmap.rename(columns={"CUSIP": "instrument"}), how="left", on="instrument")
      .merge(isinmap.rename(columns={"ISIN": "instrument"}), how="left", on="instrument", suffixes=["CUSIP", "ISIN"]))

df["ID"] = df.IDCUSIP
df.loc[df.ID.isnull(), "ID"] = df.loc[df.ID.isnull(), "IDISIN"]
df = df.drop(["IDCUSIP", "IDISIN"], axis=1)
```